# Sorting on ajax scrolling content in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, sorting

I have some 1000 of records which I want to display in divs. I'm displaying them in bundles of 20, and when you scroll to bottom loads next 20 records. I'm sorting the records on a range attribute, but when I scroll and load new 20 records in success function of my ajax call, that sorting condition of div is not working for those divs.

Those new Records are displayed in serial order without getting sorted. I'm able to sort the records in present page but if u sort and then scroll to bottom and load new records - those records are not getting sorted on scrolling.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div class="content" data-name="Peter" data-price="1000" data-location="US"><span class="productPriceForSorting">1000</span</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-name="Willy" data-price="1200" data-location="Mexico"><span class="productPriceForSorting">1200</span</div><br />

    <div class="content" data-name="Peter" data-price="2000" data-location="US"><span class="productPriceForSorting">2000</span</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-name="Willy" data-price="800" data-location="Mexico"><span class="productPriceForSorting">800</span</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-name="Willy" data-price="1300" data-location="Mexico"><span class="productPriceForSorting">1300</span</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-name="Peter" data-price="800" data-location="US"><span class="productPriceForSorting">800</span</div><br />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="prod"></div>
    <button id="asc">sort by price asd</button>
```

below is my ajax scrolled records

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var page=1;
     <%String name1=(String)session.getAttribute("name");%> 
    var name2="<%=name1%>";
    $(window).scroll(function(e) 
            {if ($(window).scrollTop()+ $(window).height() == $(document).height()) 
            {page++;


            $.ajax({    type : "Get",
                        url : "Someservlet",                        
                        datatype : "JSON",
                        contentType : 'application/json',
                        data : {pagenumber : page,
                        Pname : name2},

                        success : function(data) {

                            var data1 = data[0],

                            var len = data1.length;
                            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                                        var name = "<div class=content data-name=" + data1[i].name + '' + " data-location=" + data1[i].location + ">"
                                        + "Peter" +"</div>"+"<div class=content data-name=" + data1[i].name + '' + " data-location=" + data1[i].location + ">"
                                        + "Willy" +"</div>";

                                $(name).appendTo("#prod");
                            }

                    }

               });
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

Following is code for sorting

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function sortByPrice(a, b) {
            return $(a).find('.productPriceForSorting').text() > $(b).find(
                    '.productPriceForSorting').text();
        }

        function reorderEl1(el) {
            var container = $('#container');
            container.html('');
            el.each(function() {
                $(this).appendTo(container);
            });
        }

        $(document).ready('#asc').click(function() {
            reorderEl1($('.content').sort(sortByPrice));

        });

        </script>
```

Please help me guys, how to sort the scrolling elements once sorting is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX call generates records as following:

```
var name = "<div class=content data-name=" + data1[i].name + '' + " data-location=" + data1[i].location + ">"
         + "Peter" +"</div>"+"<div class=content data-name=" + data1[i].name + '' + " data-location=" + data1[i].location + ">"
         + "Willy" +"</div>";
```

Burt your sorting function is looking for `.productPriceForSorting` element which is not added by AJAX. That's what you need to change. Sorting function is not detecting `.productPriceForSorting` so it's not comparing.

Also your sort function is not comparing properly, it should be:

```
function sortByPrice(a, b) {
            return parseInt($(a).find('.productPriceForSorting').text()) > parseInt($(b).find('.productPriceForSorting').text());
        }
```

Here's the [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DzUF8/) of fixed sorting. Ajax is for you to be fixed. It must contain `<span class=\"productPriceForSorting\">"+data1[i].price+"</span>` or something like that.

Comment: I some how missed adding product div which is there in my code,but i missed adding here.Im adding that product div exactly after where div-container is ending.but still new product div elements are not coming sorted as i want..Please sir.its a request to please help me out.

Comment: Sorting methods seem alright. In my opinion the problem lies in the way of accessing the data. Why new content is being appended to `#prod` instead of `#container` directly as the starting set of rows?

Comment: i m appending it in product div because when i append them in container,the div structure is disarranged...any solution fr tht

Comment: if i append the new records in container,then every 20 record is getting inserted with every content div.i.e.each content div is followed by 20 new records.how to handle that sir?

Comment: After **Edit**. What code do you use for what you mentioned? Are you sure you didn't misplaced `.content` with `#container`?

Comment: ya michal .i edited the div arrangements above.please suggest sumthing can be done in div arrangments.

Comment: Are those `<span>` originally broken (not closed properly) or typo? Can't find the difference from the original code.

Comment: @Michal-This is a typo problem.PLease guide me  sir on this.

Comment: Edited once more. I've done my best to explain, the rest is for you to fix.